# Tensorflow XLA Conv1D operator not supported?

Tags: tensorflow, xla

I would like to compile a tensorflow (2.3) keras model using tfcompile. The model uses the `conv1d` operator. During compilation I get the following error:

```
INVALID ARGUMENTS: Detected unsupported operations when trying to compile graph tfcompile on XLA_CPU_JIT: Conv2D (No registered 'Conv2D' OpKernel for XLA_CPU_JIT devices compatible with node {{node model/conv1d_50/conv1d}})model/conv1d_50/conv1d
```

Not sure what this error means exactly. Does it mean XLA is missing a kernel for Conv1D or did I mess up something else?

Comment: Please can you share complete code to reproduce your issue ? so that it will be easy to provide solution. Thanks!